# Bootstrap color won't show in table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird problem. The color won't show in a table:
What am I doing wrong?

The "danger" class should as far as I know work here.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Hardware (navn)</th>
        <th>Map</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class="danger">
    <td class="danger col-md-1">
        33
    </td>

    <td class="danger col-md-2">
        Something
    </td>

    <td class="danger col-md-1">
        Something else
    </td>

    <td class="danger col-md-2">
        DATE
    </td>

    <td class="danger">
        Description.........
    </td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: What colour? You should show a [mcve].

Comment: if you want to change the [background](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color) it is .bg-danger not .danger

Answer (score 4):

For text coloring use `text-danger`, for background coloring use `bg-danger`.

As far as I know, there is no `danger` class in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by the bootstrap [color documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/).

> The class: bg-danger - Changes background color to red.
>
> The class: text-danger - Changes the font color to red.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Hardware (navn)</th>
        <th>Map</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr class="danger">
        <td class="bg-danger col-md-1">
          33
        </td>

        <td class="text-danger col-md-2">
          Something
        </td>

        <td class="danger col-md-1">
          Something else
        </td>

        <td class="danger col-md-2">
          DATE
        </td>

        <td class="danger">
          Description.........
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong class try this :

```
<td class="bg-danger  col-md-1">
    33
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap 4 , the correct class is `table-danger` see [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#contextual-classes)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Hardware (navn)</th>
        <th>Map</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class="table-danger">
    <td class="col-md-1">
        33
    </td>

    <td class="col-md-2">
        Something
    </td>

    <td class="col-md-1">
        Something else
    </td>

    <td class="col-md-2">
        DATE
    </td>

    <td class="">
        Description.........
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="">
    <td class="col-md-1">
        33
    </td>

    <td class="table-danger col-md-2">
        Something
    </td>

    <td class="col-md-1">
        Something else
    </td>

    <td class="col-md-2">
        DATE
    </td>

    <td class="table-danger">
        Description.........
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```